# D3 getting NULL for user-defined input during callback

Tags: php, jquery, d3.js

I have two input text boxes named startDate and endDate, and a submit button. I did the backend of the code in PHP so that it takes the input (dates) from the two text boxes and, after clicking the submit button, outputs a JSON file that D3 can render.

The problem is, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", but when I  input the values of startDate and endDate manually (declaring the value instead of it being a user input), it works perfectly. I'm guessing that the values of sDate and eDate aren't being passed properly during the callback, that's why it's returning NULL. I have no idea how to fix it though.

Sharing my code here.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="user" action="#" method="post"> 
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td><input id="start_date" type="text" name="startDate" value="" size="30" /> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td> <input id="end_date" type="text" name="endDate" value="" size="30" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="submit_button">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> 
            <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
</form>
<div id="contents" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>

<!-- data should appear once Submit button is clicked -->
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submitButton').click (function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                renderTable();
            });     
        });
</script>

<!-- D3 -->
<script>
function renderTable(){
    d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
                var c_data = d3.select("#contents").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 500)
                                .attr("height", 500)

                var bars = c_data.selectAll("rect")
                                .data(data)
                                .enter()
                                    .append("rect")
                                    .attr("width", function(d){return d.value * 30})
                                    .attr("height", 50)
                                    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * 80})

            })
}   
</script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO($hostname, $username,$password);
    //$startDate = '2014-11-21'; --> works when this is used
    //$endDate = '2014-11-23'; --> works when this is used

    if(isset($_POST['startDate']))
        { $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];};

    if(isset($_POST['endDate']))
        { $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];};

    $statement = $db->prepare(*SQL statement edited out*);

    $statement->execute(array($startDate, $endDate));

    $jsonData=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($jsonData);
?>
```

Additional info:

I'm getting this for data.php element:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: startDate in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myProject/data.php


Notice**:  Undefined index: endDate in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myProject/data.php
[]

Comment: Well you are not `POST`ing the form, so the data won't get sent. You could add the values to the URL you call as parameters and query them through `$_GET`.

Comment: Hi, @LarsKotthoff! I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you provide a more concrete example? I learn best when I see the code. Thank you!

Comment: Something like `d3.json("data.php?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate, function (...) { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

Forms work by sending the input values to the server by either POST or GET. (Hence their method attribute).

You are trying to access the POST variable in your php code, you aren't actually POSTing the form. It might be easier to put the variables in the url, something like this:

```
d3.json("data.php?startDate=" + startDateValue + "&endDate=" + endDateValue, funct.....
```

Among the many differences between POST and GET is that GET sends the values over the url, so the only difference in the php code would be changing the access to `$startDate = $_GET['startDate'];`

Edit: Since I realize I just basically repeated exactly what Lars Kotthoff said, [here is an interesting solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/f2wkcTTJM8Y/cZkFF6gbgDQJ) for using POST instead of GET, using [`xhr.send(method[, data][, callback])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#send)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @LarsKotthoff and @IgnacioAmpuero! I didn't exactly use the method you suggested, but it did help me understand what I was missing.

To anyone experiencing the same problem, this is what I did:

Used AJAX request to populate my query.

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'data.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#user').serialize(),
                async: false
            }).responseText;
```

Assigned the result to data.

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonData_status);
```

And then used it to generate my chart.

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500);

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){return d.value * 30})
                    .attr("height", 50)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * 80});
```